# Reading blank values from Excel and using it in script

Tags: java, webdriver

I am performing the following steps :

1. Reading values from Excel.
2. Passing the values in the fields after reading it from Excel.

(Say my Excel sheet has A1 value as 'TestUserName' I am passing it in username field. )

But currently if the cell value is blank, it's throwing `nullPointerException`. How to proceed about it?

Here in this case suppose if my A1 value is blank how to deal with such situation. I am not using arralist.

Comment: Please include minimal example code that demonstrates the issue (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it will be very hard to help you out.

Comment: How do you read a value from excel cell? Show code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just catch NullPointerException to replace it by an empty string?

For example :

```
string username ;
try
{
    //Your code that fetches Excel cells contents
    username = fetchCell("A1"); //here it throws the exception if the cell is empty
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    username = "";
}
```